# Docx mimetype not returned correctly in Spring call

Tags: java, spring, rest, mime-types

I have a Spring based controller with the following endpoint in it.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/endpoint/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public FileSystemResource getConfig(
        @PathVariable int id, 
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ApiException, IOException {

    try {
        File example = service.getExampleDoc(id);

        // docx official mime type
        mimeType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document";

        // Tried both of these seperatly
        response.setContentType(mimeType); 
        response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=example.docx");

        return new FileSystemResource(example);
    } catch (Exception e) {     
        throw e;
    } 
}
```

Whenever I make the call in a browser, the Content-Disposition is set correctly, but the Content-Type always comes back as 'text/html'

The two lines I call to set the content type:

```
   response.setContentType(mimeType); 
   response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType);
```

Have been tried independently of one another and both are included in the code snippet for completeness.

Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: Can you try removing the line response.setHeader("Content-Type", mimeType); I think it might be overriding response.setContentType(mimeType);

Comment: I've tried both lines independently, I've added them both here to show the two attempts that fail. I'll update question to make this clearer